# "Seeing the rain come on, we took shelter" — complex or simple sentence?

Tags: sentence-patterns, clauses

> Seeing the rain come on, we took shelter.

This sentence looks like a complex sentence with a main and an independent clause. But the book says it is a simple sentence. Which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The introductory phrase *Seeing the rain come on* is not a clause because it contains no subject-verb relationship. It is a so-called participial phrase.

Hence, we have only one independent clause and no dependent clauses. Your sentence, therefore, is simple.

Comment: Shouldn't that be _precipital_ phrase. :-)

Comment: The initial participial clause _seeing the rain come on_ has the subject _we_ (or _our_ in this case), which is deleted, just like the subject _we_  (or _us_) of the infinitive _to go_ is deleted in _We want to go_, because it's predictable from the subject _we_ of the main clause. So I'm afraid it's a complex sentence. Any non-auxiliary verb heads a clause, whether it's got a subject or not.